# What does Kotlin coroutines documentation mean when they say joinAll() is semantically equivalent to calling join() in sequence?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, code-documentation

In https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/join-all.html it's stated that "This method is semantically equivalent to joining all given jobs one by one with forEach { it.join() }."

I have this code

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
  joinTest()
  joinAllTest()
}

fun joinAllTest() {
  val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()
  runBlocking { (0..2).map { launch { delay1s(it) } }.joinAll() }
  val end = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println("joinAllTest took: ${end-begin}")
}

fun joinTest() {
  val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()
  runBlocking {
    for (i in 0..2) {
      val job2 = launch { delay1s(i) }
      job2.join()
    }
  }
  val end = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println("joinTest took: ${end-begin}")
}


suspend fun delay1s(i: Int) {
  delay(1000)
}
```

This produces:

```
joinTest took: 3101
joinAllTest took: 1011
```

How can join() be semantically equivalent to joinAll() with the following behavior? Calling join sequentially suspends on each join while joinAll() runs them in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Relevant source code in kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/5f60f224505580579a7f14aacd0051c055c19dc5/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Await.kt#L66)

```
public suspend fun Collection<Job>.joinAll(): Unit = forEach { it.join() }
```

The implementation tells us that the `joinAll` function is literally equal to `forEach { it.join() }`

The reason for the different timings of your functions is that in the first case, the `delay`s are performed in parallel, and in the second, each subsequent one waits for the previous one to complete.

So in your case `joinTest` should be:

```
fun joinTest() {
  val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()
  runBlocking { (0..2).map { launch { delay1s(it) } }.forEach{it.join()} }
  val end = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println("joinTest took: ${end-begin}")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code runs the jobs concurrently as desired. My misunderstanding was that I thought join() did what launch{ ... } actually appears to do. Launching starts the asynchronous computation while join simply suspends to await for the instance's completion. I need to launch{} all the jobs first before doing any join().